# I'm overlooking something: TypeError: create() got unexpected keyword argument 'system'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

It's probably a noob mistake, but I cant find the error.

Below is the project.models

```
class ProjectManager(models.Manager):
    """"""
    def create(self, owner, project_name):
        project = super().create(owner=owner, project_name=project_name)
        project.save()

        System.objects.create(project=project, system_name="System initial name")

        return project

class Project(models.Model):
    objects = ProjectManager()

    owner           = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In the system.models I now define the System and Circuit model, i.e. each project has at least one System and each System has at least one circuit.

```
class SystemManager(models.Manager):
    """"""
    def create(self, project, system_name):
        system = super().create(project=project, system_name=system_name)
        system.save()

        Circuit.objects.create(system=system, circuit_name="Primary circuit")
        return system

class System(models.Model):
    objects = SystemManager()

    project     = models.ForeignKey('solgeo.Project', related_name='systems', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    system_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, project):
        system = cls(project=project)

    def __str__(self):
        return "system name: " + str(self.system_name)

class CircuitManager(models.Manager):
    """"""
    def create(self, project, system_name):
        circuit = super().create(system=system, circuit_name=circuit_name)
        circuit.save()
        return circuit


class Circuit(models.Model):
    """Models a hydraulic circuit"""
    objects = CircuitManager()

    system = models.ForeignKey(System, related_name='circuits', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    circuit_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now I get the error: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'system'. When I comment out: Circuit.objects.create(system=system, circuit_name="Primary circuit") then the error disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create` method of `CircuitManager` has `system_name` as parameter not `system`. Change it to `system` since you are using it in the method body too.